# Find the 2nd row of data based on a column value, if not available then print NULL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am working on some project in hive and below problem is one part of it. Please note that i am going to apply the solution for this query on a subquery result /table which i have already made.

So as part of this, i am trying to print the row for each id based on column value of rnum. If rnum=2 then print both the column values, i.e., id,value. If rnum= 2 is not present for an id then then print id,'No value'.

Give below sample input and expected output.

For eg.

for id 100, since rnum is only 1, hence print value as 'No value'

for id 200, print only value for rnum=2, i.e., xyz and ignore value for rnum=1,3 and 4

Input:

```
id      value     rnum
100      abc        1
200      def        1
200      xyz        2 
200      rtz        3
200      tgv        4
```

Expected output:

```
id                value    
100                No Value
200                xyz
```

Comment: you are changing requirements on the fly

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I realized it a little late what i posted since i am fairly new to this forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `case` logic:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when mum = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when mum = 2 then value end)
             else 'No Value'
        end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just updated my input set. In case, you may want to re-look and edit the query, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below:

```
select a.id, case when t.id is null then 'No value' else t.value end
from (select distinct id as id from t) a
left join t on t.rnum = 2 and a.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select t1.id, case when t2.rnum != 1 then t2.value else 'no value' end
from (
  select count(1) as ct, id from test2
  group by id) t1
left join test2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.rnum = 2
order by t1.id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed, allowing for any id values:

```
with t2(id, cnt) as
(
select id, count(*) as cnt
from t1
group by id
)
select t1.id,
    max(case
        when t2.cnt = 1 and t1.rnum = 1 then 'No Value'
        when t2.cnt > 1 and t1.rnum = 2 then value
    end)
from t1
join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, But this is just the sample data and there are 1000's of id's in the table.

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you for your comment. I made the changes.